# ActiveMQ 5.15.5, Camel ActiveMQ component brokerURL to connect two standalone brokers

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-camel

I have two standalone broker consuming message from another system.

The client consumer uses Camel to consume messages, below is the part of the configuration where it used `camel-activemq` component.

I am trying to provide both the host information within the borkerURL but throwing some exception.
using jars of
spring-core 4.2.4,
spring-boot: 1.3.1,
activemq-camel: 5.12.1,
activemq-broker: 5.12.1, etc.

```xml
...

  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=500000" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
  </bean>
...
```

The process throw exception, when i run the camel main with the context.

```
:PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'brokerURL' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid broker URI: (tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=500000
```

Is there any way to pass in the borker URL of two standalone brokers?

Answer (score 0):

If the brokers are part of a failover system, use the "failover" protocol of the ActiveMQ client.
If the brokers have different queues, create two different commponents with different configurations and broker URLs.


refer to jms1 or jms2 in your route.